# acer aspire notebook restarting frequently

Tags: windows-7, reboot

Once I forcefully shut down my Acer notebook several times (this happened when I tried to connect my computer to my LED TV via a HDMI cable. At that time my computer was not responding).

Later I tried to start computer (win 7 OS) it goes fine till the Windows 7 welcome animation then starts restarting.

I even tried to boot Ubuntu live CD to access my files but it is also not working.

Please give me some useful information for recovering my data from the laptop hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a lot of reasons for that(HDD, processor, ...). When you restarted it something broke, and now when it boots it comes to the point where the broken thing must start, it finds out that it cant start it and reboots. In any case you should go to some service center, and there after diagnostic they will tell you what to do.

Comment: and for future: NEVER forcefully shut down a notebook

Answer (score 0):

That symptom can be caused by many reasons, but in this specific case you probably damaged the filesystem by doing a hard shutdown.

You can often fix this by doing a fsck/checkdisk.

- If you still can boot to safe mode or to a command prompt then use that.
- Otherwise boot from an install DVD, escape to the command prompt and
  run diskcheck.
- Alternatively remove the drive, connect it to another computer, run diskcheck and then return it to the original computer.